# How to unescape an escaped wide string in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal, widestring

Some of my wide strings contains characters escaped with &#
For example:
The wide string source looks like: `'&#32;&#32;&#32;'`
The converted result must be  `'   '` (3 blank spaces).

Function should look like

```
function UriUnescape(const aSrc: WideString): WideString;
begin
  //Your code goes here
end;
```

Note: 1) I am using Delphi 7.

2) This wide string is part of a SOAP response not HTML.

3) In general this method should accept alphanumeric characters as part of the wide string: example input :='be @' result := 'be @'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your C# link is about URL unescaping but your source string looks more like [HTML encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp).
In that case, see [`HtmlDecode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Web.HTTPApp.HTMLDecode) function in `HttpApp` unit.

If you want URL decoding you could try [`HttpDecode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Web.HTTPApp.HTTPDecode) or Indy's `TIdURL.URLDecode`.

Comment: @arioch which is exactly what you would want to happen

Comment: @David yes, probably. That was the point. It is easy to make ad hoc parser for [numeric SGML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) alone, maybe even easier than searching through libraries (at least definitely less dependencies), but then one day it might unexpectedly break suddenly met named ones.

Comment: These functions do not work, I still do not have the desired result (3 blanks)

Comment: @mas_oz2k1 `HtmlDecode('&#32;&#32;&#32;')` returns `'   '` (3 blanks).

Comment: HTMLDecode works OK, I was testing HTTPDecode and UrlDecode that do not work for this scenario.